# Javascript Regex to find numbers followed by 'px' or '%'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression in javascript to find numbers that are followed by `px`, `%` or no unit at all , my questions is to see if the structure of this regex is correct.

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(px|%)?
```

The application would be like this

```
var string  = '10px, 15px, 10';
var regex   = [0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(px|%)?
var matches = string.match( regex ); // return [ '10px', '15px', 10 ]
```

I've already tested it but i want to be sure if the structure is correct.

Comment: "Succeeded by," not "preceded by." pre = before

Comment: Shouldn't it be a question for codereview.se ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems fine, other than that you've forgotten to put the regex in regex quotes, and you probably want it not to be case sensitive, so:

```
var regex   = /[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(px|%)?/i;
```

Note that `[0-9]` could be `\d`. Also, if you're not using the capture group, you could make that a non-capturing group. So:

```
var regex   = /\d*\.?\d+(?:px|%)?/i;
```

You're not allowing for whitespace after the digits and before the `px`/`%`, but I figure that's intentional.

Comment: The regex in this answer works. I suggest using this: `/^(^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)$/`
It will let you get both negative and positive numbers with any kind if unit at the end. Example output from match on string `-13px` is `["-13px", "-13", "px"]`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, your regex would also match `.2`

Try this:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(px|%)?
```

Explanation:

`[0-9]+` is the number

`(\.[0-9]+)?` is the optional fraction part

`(px|%)?` is the optional unit.

By the way, you can use `\d` for digits if you like. Some would say that it is more readable:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?
```

Comment: *"your regex would also match .2 or 6p%"* No, the alternation will be between `px` and `%`. It will match .2, which is a valid number format in many contexts.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right about the alternation part, just tested it and made an update of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
var regex = /[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?=px|%|\b)/i;
```

`(?=px|%|\b)` will match the numbers followed by `px`, `%` or the word boundary.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG0yA7/2)

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this.

```
/\d*\.?\d+(?:px|%)?/g
```